# Can a tqdm progress bar be applied to filtered SQL queries inside flask-SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, tqdm

I am using a `flask-sqlalchemy` session in which I have a simple query which returns a list:

```
results = db.session.query(Item).filter(Item.score > 0).all()
```

Since I have no idea how long it will take to complete the query, I'd like to see a progress bar.

The answer offered here does not seem to acknowledge the problem with creating chunks from the earlier read operation. [Can tqdm be used with Database Reads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282478/can-tqdm-be-used-with-database-reads) In my case, I'm not using `pandas` either.